# Python how to Chart multiple years values over the same x-axis?

Tags: python, charts

> not sure this can be done tbh. I want to chart over the same x-axis
> which is daily (1-31) multiple years of data.
>
> My data represent futures price spreads of variable 'KE' and 'MW' over
> several years but the same futures month (N). I'd like to plot a line unique to each year the spread
> (MWN-KEN) over the daily x-axis
>
> the issue is the Date is staggered as some contracts spread expire,
> others begin to trade..etc

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int)
df['WeekNumber'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().day
commodity1 = 'MW'
commodity2 = 'KE'
futures_month1 = 'N'
futures_month2 = 'N'
results = []
for year in range(2004, 2023):
    commodity1_df = df[(df['Commodity'] == commodity1) & (df['FuturesMonth'] == futures_month1) & (df['Year'] == year)][['Date', 'Close']]
    commodity2_df = df[(df['Commodity'] == commodity2) & (df['FuturesMonth'] == futures_month2) & (df['Year'] == year)][['Date', 'Close']]
    merged_df = pd.merge(commodity1_df, commodity2_df, on=['Date'], suffixes=('_' + commodity1, '_' + commodity2)).dropna()
    merged_df['Day'] = merged_df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().day
    merged_df['Spread'] = merged_df['Close_' + commodity1] - merged_df['Close_' + commodity2]
    merged_df.set_index('Day', inplace=True)
    merged_df['Year'] = year
    results.append(merged_df)
spread_df = pd.concat(results)
print(spread_df)
```